# How to handle switching from mobile chrome browser to android native like sms, google playstore and vice-versa?

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

**Selenium :** 3.0.0

**chromedriver :** 2.36

**Appium :** 1.7.2

**Android Chromebrowser** : 65.0.32..

**Requirement:**

**Scenario1:**

1.Open mobile browser page

2.Click on one button

3.Now the android Google playstore screen should be displayed.

4.Comeback to the mobile browser again.

**Scenario2:**

1.Open mobile browser page

2.Click on one button

3.Now the android SMS should be displayed.

4.Comeback to the mobile browser again.

```
      public class KindleModule extends LaunchApp {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws       MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LaunchApp app = new LaunchApp();
    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver=capabilities();
    //WebDriver driver; 
    driver.get("https:abc");
    System.out.println("application launched");
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='abc']/div/")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    //after clicking this button i want to navigate to playstore because example kindle app is not present and after that i want to come back:

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=abcPopup']/button")).click();

    Activity activity = new Activity("appPackage", "appActivity");
    //redirect to the Activity
    driver.startActivity(activity);  




    }
```

}

Can someone please help how to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

I have also got the same issue when I stared mobile automation. After research, I got a solution and it's working fine.

Try below example, I think it should work for you.

Solutions for your both scenarios:

1. Open mobile browser page
2. Click on one button
3. Now the android Google playstore screen should be displayed.

   ```
   //Wait until Google playstore screen not appear. I'm using Thread.sleep() method due to some performance issue.
   Thread.sleep(2000);

   //Comeback to the mobile browser again. For that you have to use appPackage and appActivity which you want to open name as below.
   //e.g. Activity activity = new Activity("com.test.app", "com.test.app.MainActivity");
   Activity activity = new Activity("com.android.chrome", "com.android.chrome.app.Main");
   //redirect to the Activity
   driver.startActivity(activity);
   System.out.println("app opened");
   ```

Please let me know if you have any concerns related to this.

Comment: @ Bhavin Dholakiya I want to switch from mobile browser to google play app.But after clicking on the button it remains on the same page.Can you please help me for solving this.

Comment: @akhouri Please put your sample code in your question. So it will better to explain you in your code.

Comment: @akhouri, did you try with the updated answer? You can also get current opened activity by using `driver.currentActivity()`.

Comment: @ BhavinD i added the same but it didnt work for me :(